# border-box with position:fixed doesn't show padding in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, navigation, css-position, border-box

*// EDIT:
See this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hotu2n91/ As you can see, this is the same problem with a minimal test environment*

I am having trouble with positioning my navigation. While you are reading you can view the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/vgugd8no/

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body, html{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.overlay{
    position:fixed;
    background:blue;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}  
    .overlay .content{
        width:100%;
        height:400px;
        background:yellow;
        border-right:10px solid black;
    }
    .overlay .navigation{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:300px;
        height:100%;
        overflow:auto;
        background:green;
        /* !IMPORTANT */
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        z-index:10;
        padding-bottom:20px;
    }
```

As you can see I have a `position:fixed;` overlay and a navigation also with `position:fixed;` in it. Now I want to remove for example 20px from the navigation, but remain 100%. So the value would be 100%-20px. This is what `box-sizing:border-box;` is for. But currently it will not work in FireFox and I need some help. I want to adjust the navigation so that it will not overlap the content scrollbar. Why does my `box-sizing:border-box;` not work?

Comment: What's your actual question? The padding of 20px at the bottom shows up just fine. Also, don't use inline styling. I made a demo with the styles in the CSS section as they should be [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/hotu2n91/1/)

Comment: I am using FF v30 and for me the padding will not appear. What browser / OS do you use?

Comment: I see. You should test cross browser before posting :P I'm on Chrome 37

Comment: Don’t know why Firefox doesn’t like this … but would offer `div:after { display:block; content:""; height:20px; }` as a quick fix resp. workaround.

Comment: @CBroe see this fiddle with your changes: http://jsfiddle.net/hotu2n91/2/ as you can see, nothing did change

Comment: Is see 20px of blank space at the bottom of the div, in Firefox 32.0/Win7 – don’t you? (Maybe [add a `background-color`](http://jsfiddle.net/hotu2n91/3/) to the pseudo element, that should make it more obvious.)

Comment: Ok now I see what you mean. But this is not what I was searching for. This will not crop the box at the bottom -20px, it will only set a inline padding of 20px. I want that the complete box will reduce -20px at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can try it wrap into `.wrapper` here is example. Then it'll be work as a charm. I suspect that ff cant mesure properly height and then it can't set padding. That's what for wrapper is. That's my guess. And it's not first time when ff have problem with similiar issue.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/4ovuxzrc/)